# Magento 2 | Observe ajax calls in one page checkout

Tags: magento2, event-observer, shipping, onepage-checkout, ajax

I'm looking for a way to observe ajax calls on opc page for e.g. when user changes shipping address.

I'm rendering additional fields for carriers, but when user changes address default shipping methods table comes back.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

var_dump and print_r wont work. I use xdebug in my Ide with a plugin for xdebug in the Browser.

Another solution is to write the data you are interested in into a log file.

You can also use software like fiddler, wireshark .... to watch the traffic.